# NPN transistor base collector biasing

Tags: transistors

Is it recommended to operate an npn transistor in a open collector switch mode where the base driving voltage is 12 v and collector pull up voltage is 5 v?

I have a practical situation where base is tied to 12V and pull up resistor of 4.7k is connected to 5V at collector.
How will the NPN transistor behave?

Comment: So where is the emitter pin connected?  Is there a series resistor on the base? Can you draw out your circuit?

Comment: If the base is tied to 12V and the emitter grounded the transistor will probably be destroyed.